# WordPress: ID текущего пункта меню

Tags: wordpress

Мне нужно получить ID текущего пункта меню, чтобы сопоставить его с со списком, который я получаю, используя `wp_get_nav_menu_items()`.

Проблема в том, что если сделать дамп того, что мне отдает `wp_get_nav_menu_items()`, то в нем в полях "ID", "db_id" и "object_id" я вижу ID из базы данных (четырехзначный, допустим, номер). А `get_queried_object_id()` выдает мне, видимо, что-то другое (1-2 значный номер).

Как получить ID именно текущего пункта конкретного меню?

Answer (score 3):

Откройте dev tools в браузере и посмотрите на html-код меню. Все id там присутствуют.

В меню есть класс для активного пункта, называется current-menu-item.

Comment: Совершенно верно, присутствуют в html-коде и сразу все. А мне надо до вывода, т.е. еще в php получить ID, причем именно текущего пункта.

Comment: что значит - текущего? тот, который отмечен active?

Comment: Вы что хотите сделать, поясните. Возможно, вы вообще не там решение ищете

Comment: Вполне возможно, давайте попробуем. У меня есть сайт с несколькими меню. Я нахожусь на странице, скажем, категории, эта страница в каждом из меню соответствует какому-то пункту. Я беру конкретное меню и мне надо знать ID того его пункта, который сейчас активен. Т.е. соответствующего странице, на которой я сейчас нахожусь.

Comment: Зачем вам это знать? Какова конечная цель?

Comment: Зная это, я могу передать это значение в JS, средствами JS уже в html-коде найти элемент, соответствующий именно текущему пункту меню и произвести с ним необходимые преобразования. Т.е. речь идет об эффектах, которые должны быть применены конкретно к текущему пункту меню.

Comment: Ничего не понимаю. Зачем передавать? Найти текущий пункт меню в js - вообще не проблема. Класс active

Comment: Там нет такого класса. Я не знаю, как это объяснить, т.к. я работаю с данным проектом далеко не с начала. Но это правда, там его действительно нет. Могу ссылку дать.

Comment: Дайте посмотреть

Comment: http://ishopddaru.temp.swtest.ru/katalog/karnizy-optom/eksklyuzivnye-karnizy/ - речь идет о боковом меню.

Comment: Есть этот класс, называется current-menu-item http://take.ms/qRvl5

Comment: Огромное спасибо, теперь гораздо легче!

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.

Comment: @KAGGDesign стоит перенести ответ (ту часть, которая помогла топикастеру) из комментариев в прямо в тело ответа.

Comment: @PashaPash перенёс, но все равно ответ с вопросом не стыкуется. Типичная проблема XY.